# Show that for the triples $V \subset H \subset V^{*}$, the following are true

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space equipped with scalar product $(,)$ and the corresponding norm $|\cdot|$. Let $V \subset H$ be a linear subspace that is dense in $H$. Assume that $V$ is a Banach space for $\|\cdot\|$. Assume also that the injection from $V$ to $H$ is continuous i.e $|v| \le C\|v\|,\forall v \in V $. Consider the operator $$T: H \to V^*$$ defined by $$ (Tu,v)_{V^*,V}=(u,v), \forall u \in H, \forall v \in V$$

1. Prove that $\|Tu\|_{V^*} \le C|u|, \forall u \in H$

Ans: $\|Tu\|_{V^*}=\sup_{\|v\| \le 1}|(Tu,v)|_{V^*,V}=\sup_{\|v\| \le 1}|(u,v)| \le |u||v| \le \sup_{\|v\| \le 1}C|u|\, \|v\| \le C|u|$

2. Prove that $T$ is injective

Ans: Suppose that $Tu=0$ for some $u \in H$. Then $(Tu,v)=0, \forall v \in V \implies (u,v)=0, \forall v \in V$. Since $V$ is dense in $H$, there exists a sequence $\{v_n\}\in V$ which converges to $u$. Then $(u,v_n) \to (u,u)$ and hence $u=0$.

3. Prove that $R(T)$ is dense in $V^*$ if $V$ is reflexive.

This I am unable to show. Any hints for this? I know that the map $J(V)=V^{**}$. But How do I construct a sequence?

4. Given $f \in V^*$, prove that $f \in R(T)$ iff there is a constant $a \ge 0$ such that $|(f,v)_{V^{*},V}| \le a|v|, \forall v \in V$

Ans: Suppose there is  constant $a \ge 0$ such that $|(f,v)_{V^{*},V}| \le a|v|, \forall v \in V$. Then Define a map $\phi: V \to K$ by $\phi(v)=(f,v)_{V^*,V}$. Then $\phi$ is continuous  and since $V$ is dense in $H$ , it can be extended to $\tilde{\phi}:H \to K$ . Then since $H$ is a Hilbert space, by the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists $v_f \in H$ such that $\tilde{\phi}(u)=(v_f,u), \forall u \in H $. Then $(Tv_f,v)=(v_f,v)=(f,v), \forall v\in V$. Hence $f \in R(T)$. The other side is trivial.

The only thing that remains to show is $3$ and I have not used that $V$ is Banach with respect to $\|\cdot\|$. How do I show it? I need a hint.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Four questions is a bit much for one post...

Comment: This is a single question in the book. It has just four simple bits. A hint would suffice for the third bit.